# pass dynamic values in API params coming from navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I got following 2 values in id and company variable by navigating the screen.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.route && props.route.params) {
      console.log("id-->", props.route.params.oved);
      console.log("company-->", props.route.params.company);
    }
  });
```

e,g i got 2 values like this

```
id--> 31
company--> 465
```

I want to pass the id and company value in API params.

**api.js : -**

```
const AllFormCardAPI = () => {
  const [formAllAPIData, setAllFormAPIData] = useState("");
  //NOTE: retrieving loginAuthToken from store
  const loginAuthToken = useSelector(
    (state) => state.loginAuthTokenReducer.loginAuthToken
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(GET_ALL_FORM, {
        //TODO: take parameters from user data currently parameters are static
        params: {
          company: "984",
          employee: "38887683",
          DisplayRow: "123456",
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${loginAuthToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((data) => setAllFormAPIData(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          //NOTE: handling token expire
          return ExpireAlertRestart();
        } else {
          Alert.alert(error.message);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => console.log("finally block all form api", formAllAPIData));
  }, []);
};
```

i want to pass those 2 values i,e **id** and **company** from navigation which I mentioned above and those has to be passed **as** **string** to following in API params.

My new API params should look like this. The id value should replace in **employee** params and **company** value should replace in company params.

```
 params: {
          company: "465",
          employee: "31",
```

action.js:--

```
import { CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY } from "./action-constants";
export const changeCompany = (updatedCompany, updatedId) => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY,
    updatedCompany,
    updatedId,
  };
};
```

reducer.js:--

```
import { CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY } from "../actions/action-constants";

const initialState = {
  company: "",
  id: "",
};
const changeCompanyReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY:
      return {
        company: {
          company: action.updatedCompany,
          id: action.updatedId,
        },
      };
    
  }
  return state;
};

export default changeCompanyReducer;
```

congigure-store.js:--

```
import changeCompanyReducer from "./reducers/change-company-reducer";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({changeCompanyReducer});
```

How can i store the update values getting from navigation in Redux?

could you please write code for redux??

Answer (score 0):

```
    const AllFormCardAPI = (props) => {
//New lines
    const id = props?.route?.params?.oved;
const company = props?.route?.params?.company;
//New lines end
      const [formAllAPIData, setAllFormAPIData] = useState("");
      //NOTE: retrieving loginAuthToken from store
      const loginAuthToken = useSelector(
        (state) => state.loginAuthTokenReducer.loginAuthToken
      );
      useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(GET_ALL_FORM, {
            //TODO: take parameters from user data currently parameters are static
            params: {
              company: company,
              employee: id,
              DisplayRow: "123456",
            },
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${loginAuthToken}`,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => response.data)
          .then((data) => setAllFormAPIData(data))
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              //NOTE: handling token expire
              return ExpireAlertRestart();
            } else {
              Alert.alert(error.message);
            }
          })
          .finally(() => console.log("finally block all form api", formAllAPIData));
      }, []);
    };
```

Comment: i am getting error e.g.undefined in console of the company and id.@Ram Rana

Comment: Are you getting params or not?
Can you tell what props are you getting ?

Comment: i am not getting params..it is displaying undefined and in props i am getting  like this:--
props---> 2016
props---> 2017
props---> 2019
props---> 2020

Comment: It means you are navigating wrong, Check the navigation

Comment: from navigation i am getting correct values...

Comment: Can you show how are you navigating? Few lines of code.

Comment: selection-screen:---
```
const gotToLoadingScreen = (item) => {
    props.navigation.navigate("LoadingScreen", {
      //screen: LOADING_SCREEN,
      oved: inputValue.oved,
      company: item,
    });
  };
```
loading-screen.js:--
```
let id = props.route.params.oved;
  let company = props.route.params.company;
```

Comment: ohhh! So where are you calling this AllFormCardAPI component. You need to pass to this component also the params.